# Making Command, Option and Control work with microsoft sculpt keyboard?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, keyboard

I'm trying to set up the command keys on my 2014 macbook pro (10.10.1 Yosemite) with my new wireless microsoft sculpt keyboard:

[image: Sculpt]

I went into my system prefs and started trying to make it so I could map the ctrl button to macs command button with no luck (note I set it back to default after):

[image: prefs]

Now I'm using Karabiner and trying to map the keys ctrl_l to command_l, but it still doesn't seem to be working.

*edit*

The Key mappings are working on the macs keyboard, but not my sculpt keyboard.

*edit 2*

I mapped the return key to command and now when I hit enter on my sculpt it acts as if it is the command button. I just now need to figure out what the ctrl and alt button are mapped to by default on the sculpt. Any ideas?

*edit 3*

In the event viewer in the Karabiner program when I push down the ALT and CTRL buttons they don't get picked up. But when I push down the windows button it is registered already as the command_l and the button between the right CTRL and ALT registers as as PC_application. Now I need to figure out if I can get the CTRL and ALT buttons working or how to just register the pc_app button as options and call it a day.

Answer (score 1):

In system preferences hit restore to default then ok. Download [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/)

and then in Karabiner do this:

[image]